# onItemClickListener not firing on custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an `Activity` that retrieves data from a web service. This data is presented in a `ListView` via an ArrayAdapter which inflates a `RelativeLayout` with three `TextViews` inside, nothing fancy and it work fine.

Now I want to implement a Details `Activity` that should be called when a user clicks an item in the ListView, sounds easy but I can't for the life of me get the onItemClickListener to work on my ArrayAdapter.

This is my main `Activity`:

```
public class Schema extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Lesson> lessons = new ArrayList<Lesson>();
    private static final String TAG = "Schema";
    ListView lstLessons;
    Integer lessonId;

    // called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // can we use the custom titlebar?
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        // set the view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // set the title
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);

        // listview called lstLessons
        lstLessons = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstLessons);

        // load the schema
        new loadSchema().execute();

        // set the click listeners
        lstLessons.setOnItemClickListener(selectLesson);      

    }// onCreate

// declare an OnItemClickListener for the AdapterArray (this doesn't work)
private OnItemClickListener selectLesson = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int i, long l) {  
        Log.v(TAG, "onItemClick fired!");
    }                
};

private class loadSchema extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog; 

    // ui calling possible
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Schema.this,"", "Please wait...", true);
    }

    // no ui from this one
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // get some JSON, this works fine
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // apply to list adapter
        lstLessons.setAdapter(new LessonListAdapter(Schema.this, R.layout.list_item, lessons));        
    }
```

My ArrayAdapter code:

```
// custom ArrayAdapter for Lessons 
private class LessonListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lesson> {
    private ArrayList<Lesson> lessons;

    public LessonListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Lesson> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.lessons = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        Lesson o = lessons.get(position);

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timestarttext);
        TextView rt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.roomtext);

        v.setClickable(true);
        v.setFocusable(true);

        tt.setText(o.title);
        bt.setText(o.fmt_time_start);
        rt.setText(o.room);
        return v;
    }
}// LessonListAdapter
```

The main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    >

    <!-- student name -->
    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/schema_view_student"
      android:text="Name"  android:padding="4dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
      style="@style/schema_view_student"
    />

    <!-- date for schema -->    
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/schema_view_title"   
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="0dip" 
      style="@style/schema_view_day"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
      android:layout_below="@+id/schema_view_student"         
      android:text="Date" android:padding="6dip"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

    <!-- horizontal line -->
    <View
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dip"
      android:background="#55000000"
      android:layout_below="@+id/schema_view_title"
    />

    <!--  list of lessons -->
    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/lstLessons" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/schema_view_title"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px"
    android:padding="12dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestarttext"
        android:text="09:45"
        style="@style/LessonTimeStartText"

        android:layout_width="60dip"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:paddingRight="6dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titletext"
        android:text="Test"
        style="@style/LessonTitleText"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timestarttext"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roomtext"
        android:text="123"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        style="@style/LessonRoomText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Been messing with this for the last couple of hours and I can't seem to get my head around what the problem is. My problem looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066220/get-specific-item-property-on-onlistitemclick-using-custom-arrayadapter), but I'm not extending ListActivity, so I still don't know where my onListClickItem() should go.

**UPDATE:** Now I've puzzled with this for several days and still can't find the issue.

Should I rewrite the activity, this time extending ListActivity instead of Activity? Because it provides the onItemClick method itself and is probably easier to overwrite.

Or, should I bind a listener directly in each getView() in my ArrayAdapter? I believe I have read this is bad practice (I should do as I tried and failed in my post).

Comment: I cannot figure it out neither of these two things helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237218/android-listview-onitemclicklistener-being-blocked-by-progressbar

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Found the bug - it seems to be [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414). Adding `android:focusable="false"` to each of the list_item.xml elements solved the issue, and the onclick is now triggered with the original code.

Comment: It took me over an hour to find your solution (which works).  Android platform can be brilliant, but this is a total failure on their part.

Comment: Seems like trackball/dpad issue. But thanks, this one solved that.

Answer (score 35):

I've encountered the same issue and tried your fix but couldn't get it to work. What worked for me was adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the `<RelativeLayout>` from the item layout `xml`,  `list_item.xml` in your case. This allows `onItemClick()` to be called.

Comment: android:focusable="false" and android:desendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" both did not work for me.

Comment: if there is a `android:clickable="true"` remove it.

Comment: The issue for me only started happening when I added a `CheckBox` to my item view. Setting the `CheckBox` to not be focusable resolved my issue. However, I like this solution better because it handles it for all child views in case I do it again in the future or another chile `View` class is defaulted to be focusable.

Comment: I hate to say 'me too' ... but this did resolve this same problem for me.  I just wish I really understood why.

Comment: Thank you. To add my anecdote, follandroid:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" worked for me as long as android:clickable="true" was removed (which I had errantly added earlier in trying to find resolution).

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me :

1) Adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to Relative Layout tag.
The result is shown below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```

2) Adding android:focusable="false" to every element in in list_item.xml 
 example :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:text="TextView"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the parent of the cell layout worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Once I had a similar problem. Every list item had a text view and a checkbox, and just because the checkbox, the whole listitem wasn't '*enabled*' to fire the event. I solved it by making a little trick inside the adapter when I was getting the view.

Just before returning the view I put:

```
v.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

(The object `listener` is an `onItemClickListener` I gave to the `Adapter`'s constructor).

But I have to tell you, the problem is because the platform, it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I tried to solve it by adding

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

to my item.xml but it still doesn't work !!! Infact I found the issue in the relative layout witch contains

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:focusable="true"
```

And when I removed it All things is ok

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
     progressDialog.dismiss();  stLessons.setAdapter(new LessonListAdapter(Schema.this, R.layout.list_item, lessons)); 
    //add this  
ListView lv = getListView();  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            });
     }
```

Comment: "The method getListView() is undefined for the type Schema.loadSchema" - wouldn't lv be the same as lstLessons anyway (lstLessons is the ListView)?

Comment: I think it may be because Schema is not extending a ListActivity.