# OnItemCLickListener not working in listview

Tags: android, listview

`Activity` class code:

```
conversationList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
ConversationArrayAdapter conversationArrayAdapter=new  ConversationArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.conversation_list_item_format_left, conversationDetails);
conversationList.setAdapter(conversationArrayAdapter);
conversationList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Log.d("test","clicked");
    }
});
```

The `getView` function in the `Adapter` class:

```
if (v == null) {                                
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(leftSideMessageNumber.equals(m.getTo())) {
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.conversation_list_item_format_left, null);
    } else {
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.conversation_list_item_format_right, null);
    }
}
```

Is there a problem with using two xmls while inflating?

Comment: @hiei My issue was that i was using imagebuttons in my layout cells. Even after adding "android:descendantFocusability" my click listener was not responding. What i did was, i changed all the ImaegButtons to ImageViews. That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 750):

I just found a solution from here, but by deep clicking.

If any row item of list contains focusable or clickable view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work.

The row item must have a param like 
`android:descendantFocusability = "blocksDescendants"`.

Here you can see an example of how your list item should look like.
Your list item xml should be...
`row_item.xml` (`your_xml_file.xml`)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    // your other widgets here

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can also set this programatically with `listView.setDescendantFocusability(int focus);` where `focus` is one of `ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS`, `ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS` or `ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS`

Comment: My question is this is an android bug or is it by design?

Comment: Hours trying to figure this out! Thanks. Note that with nested LinearLayouts for a row item, the top-most LinearLayout must not have android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants". All others need it.

Answer (score 96):

The problem is that your layouts contain either focusable or clickable items.
If a view contains either focusable or clickable item the OnItemCLickListener won't be called.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget) for more information.

Please post one of your layout xmls if that isn't the case.

Answer (score 72):

For my lists, my rows have other things that can be clicked, like buttons, so doing a blanket blocksDescendants doesn't work. Instead I add a line in the button's xml:

```
    android:focusable="false"
```

That keeps the buttons from blocking the clicks on the rows, but still lets the buttons take the clicks, too.

Comment: Only way I could get a GridView with RadioButtons in it working was to apply     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the LinearLayout containing the RadioButton, and by setting android:clickable="false" in the RadioButton itself.

Answer (score 38):

**you need to do 2 steps in your listview_item.xml**

1. set the root layout with: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
2. set any focusable or clickable view in this item with:
   `android:clickable="false"` 
   `android:focusable="false"`
   `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

**Here is an example: listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/script_name_radio_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Setting `clickable="true` on the item view will make the `onItemClick` to not be called. So pay attention to also add `clickable="false"` on the item root view, in this case is the `LinearLayout`

Comment: If you have the same layout as landscape, etc. make sure you do it there as well.

Answer (score 22):

use the below code inside button tag in custom row layout of listview

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:clickable="false"
```

Answer (score 19):

Use **android:descendantFocusability**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:background="@color/light_green"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```

Add above in root layout

Comment: Adding details might make this a better answer and +1.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and I just saw I had accidentally set:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
    return false;
}
```

on my CustomListViewAdapter class.

By changing this to:

```
return true;
```

I've managed to fix the problem.
Just in case if someone has done the same mistake...

Answer (score 11):

I solved it with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14915758/5740760)

1.Add the following in Linear Layout of list_items.xml
  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

2.Child Views of LinearLayout in list_items.xml

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 10):

if you have textviews, buttons or stg clickable or selectable in your row view only

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

is not enough. You have to set

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

to your textviews and

```
android:focusable="false"
```

to your buttons and other focusable items.

Answer (score 10):

Even I was having the same problem, I am having checkbox, did the following to masker itemClickListener work,

Added the following properties to the checkbox,

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

and ItemClickListner started working.

For detailed example you can go through the link,

http://knowledge-cess.com/android-itemclicklistner-with-checkbox-or-radiobutton/

Hope it helps Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and tried all of the mentioned solutions to no avail. through testing i found that making the text selectable was preventing the listener to be called. So by switching it to false, or removing it my listener was called again.

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

hope this helps someone who was stuck like me.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add this in main Layout

   ```
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   ```
2. Write this code into every button,Textview,ImageView etc which have
   onClick

   ```
   android:focusable="false"

   android:clickable="false"
   ```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Two awesome solutions were this, if your extending ListFragment from a fragment, know that `mListView.setOnItemClickListener` wont be called before your activity is created, this ensured it is set when activity has been created

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long rowId) {
            // Do the onItemClick action

            Log.d("ROWSELECT", "" + rowId);
        }
    });
}
```

While looking at the source code for ListFragment, I came across this

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    ...........................................
    ................................................

    final private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnClickListener
                = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            onListItemClick((ListView)parent, v, position, id);
        }
    };

    ................................................................
    ................................................................

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    }
}
```

An `onItemClickListener` object is attached and it calls `onListItemClick()`
As such the other similar solution, which works in the exact same way is to override `onListItemClick()`

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long rowId) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   // Do the onItemClick action

   Log.d("ROWSELECT", "" + rowId);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case none of xml layout properties was not helpful.

I just add a single line of code like this:
**convertView.setClickable(false);**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_id, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ...
    convertView.setClickable(false);
    return convertView;
}
```

so basically it do the same thing as setting up properties in xml layout but it was only thing which works in my case.

It is not perfect timing but maybe it will helps somebody
Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the above and NOTHING worked.

I solved the problem as follows:

First I define a custom Button called `ListButton`

```
public class ListButton extends android.widget.Button
{

private ButtonClickedListener clickListener;

public ListButton(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
}

public ListButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ListButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setClickListener(ButtonClickedListener listener) {
    this.clickListener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean isInTouchMode() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) 
      {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

              eventClicked();

              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              break;
          default :

      }
    return true;
}

private void eventClicked() {
    if (this.clickListener!=null) {
        this.clickListener.ButtonClicked();
    }
}

}
```

The XML looks like:

```
<dk.example.views.ListButton
android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
android:layout_width="125dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:text="Cancel"
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:padding="2dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textStyle="bold"  
/>
```

Then I define my own `ButtonClicked` Listener interface:

```
public interface ButtonClickedListener {
    public void ButtonClicked();
}
```

Then I use my own listener just as if it was the normal `OnClickListener`:

```
final ListButton cancelButton = (ListButton) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

    cancelButton.setClickListener(new ButtonClickedListener() {

        @Override
        public void ButtonClicked() {
            //Do your own stuff here...
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Android:autoText attribute also makes TextView auto focusable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was using a style for my texts in the row layout that had the "focusable" attribute. It worked after I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to remove the next line from the `Layout`

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both the simple click and long click on list view items better way to implement that would be to use context menu for long click. Avoid using setItemLongClickListener especially if you have multiple row layouts for your listview.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem, tried for hours. If you have tried all of the above than try changing layout_width of Listview and list item to match_parent from wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above failed for me.  However, I was able to resolve the problem (after many hours of banging my head - Google, if you're listening, please consider fixing what I encountered below in the form of compiler errors, if possible)

You really have to be careful of what android attributes you add to your  xml layout here (in this original question, it is called list_items.xml).  For me, what was causing the problem was that I had switched from an EditText view to a TextView and had leftover attribute cruft from the change (in my case, inputType).  The compiler didn't catch it and the clickability just failed when I went to run the app.  Double check all of the attributes you have in your layout xml nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
 .......

final View view = convertView;
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (onItemClickListener != null) {
             onItemClickListener.onItemClick(null, view, position, -1);
         }
      }
 });

return convertView;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
```

Then in your activity, use **adapter.setOnItemClickListener()** before attaching it to the listview.

## Copied from [github](https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout/issues/6#issuecomment-219076391) its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was to add the below code to every subview inside the layout of my row.xml file:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

So in my case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/testingId"
        android:text="Name"
       //other stuff 
        />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/dummyId"
        android:text="icon"
        //other stuff 
        />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/assignmentColor"
       //other stuff 
       />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/testID"
        //other stuff 
        />

    <TextView
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="TextView"
        //other stuff 
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my setOnItemClickListener call in my Fragment subclass:

```
CustomListView = (PullToRefreshListCustomView) layout.findViewById(getListResourceID());
        CustomListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        CustomListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Testing", "onitem click working");
              //  other code
            }

        });
```

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20697618/6464880)!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with onClick. The solution was to remove from the xml the following

```
android:tooltipText=""
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by removing the clickable views from the list.