# ListView with OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I am using a custom [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with `RatingBar` and `ImageButton`. Here is my problem: When I click on my `ListView`, my `OnItemClickListener` is not working. Please can any one help me.
Code:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
setContentView(lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: please add some code. And why is not working? An error?

Comment: i am not getting any error even if am debugging also it is not going inside.. i will post some code.

Comment: @gujjula nikhilreddy Post some Code.

Comment: ListView lv = getListView();
    setContentView(lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
      Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
     }
    });
   }

Comment: i have posted code can u cehck it out plz

Comment: I've already checked on this problem before. <br/>
Check on my article to find causes and solutions: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/
<br/>
I guess you meet Scenario 3.

Comment: @gujjulanikhilreddy: try to remove the line `setContentView(lv)`

Comment: i have removed even though it's not working..

Comment: I found the answer in this post, the first comment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Though a very old question, but I am still posting an answer to it so that it may help some one.
If you are using any layout inside the list view then use ...

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

... on the first parent layout inside the list. This works as magic the click will not be consumed by any element inside the list but will directly go to the list item.

Answer (score 22):

I have an Activity that extends ListActivity.

I tried doing something like this in onCreate:

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        Log.i("Hello!", "Y u no see me?");

    }

});
```

But that didn't work.

Instead I simply needed to override onListItemClick:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Log.i("Hello!", "Clicked! YAY!");

}
```

Answer (score 18):

Hey check this, works for me... hope it work for u too

If list item contains `ImageButton`

Problem: `OnItemClickListener` just doesn’t repond any at all!

Reason: No idea

Solution: in code, set `ImageButton`'s focus to `“false”`

1: `ImageButton button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);`

2:  `button.setFocusable(false);`

Answer (score 13):

If you want to **enable item click** in list view use

```
listitem.setClickable(false);
```

this may seem wrong at first glance but it works!

Comment: If doing it in XML make sure to make the actual child (not the parent layout) non-clickable. Also, this answer should be higher!

Answer (score 11):

if list item view contains button or checkbox or imagebutton, 
the onitemclicklistener and onitemlongclicklistener  not working due to it has own onclick listener.

set focusable as false

```
holder.button.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 9):

1) Check if you are using OnItemClickListener or OnClickListener (which is not supported for ListView)
[Documentation Android Developers ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.view.View.OnItemClickListener%29)

2) Check if you added Listener to your ListView properly. It's hooked on ListView not on ListAdapter!

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

3) If you need to use OnClickListener, check if you do use `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` or `View.OnClickListener` (they can be easily exchanged if not validated or if using both of them)

Comment: the code which i am using i have extend an listactivity. here is my codeListView lv = getListView();
    setContentView(lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
      Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
     }
    });
   }

Answer (score 5):

```
listPaired = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView1 );
listPairedData = new ArrayList < String >();
araPaired = new ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listPairedData );
listPaired.setAdapter( araPaired );
listPaired.setOnItemClickListener( listPairedClickItem );

private OnItemClickListener listPairedClickItem = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        String info = ( (TextView) arg1 ).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), "Item " + info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `lambda`. Lambda syntax is not supported under Java 1.7 or earlier JVMs.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

setClickable as false to ImageButton like this

```
imagebutton.setClickable(false);
```

and then perform `OnItemClickListener` to listview.

Answer (score 4):

If you define your ListView programatically:

```
mListView.setDescendantFocusability(ListView.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java as other suggest

```
listitem.setClickable(false);
```

Or in xml:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

It works very fine

Answer (score 1):

Is there and image in the list view that you are using>
then follow the link:
http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/

I think when you work out on the link that I have provided first every thing will work fine, I have tried that. If you want a refined answer please elaborate the question with code and description.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the line into RatingBar:

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```

In XML the ratingbar look like this.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Android OnItemClickLIstener conflicts with the OnClickListener of items of row of listview in Adapter. You just have to make sure your code is well managed and properly written with standards.

Check the answer in the link given below:

[Make list clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836384/make-list-clickable/43836958#43836958)

Answer (score 1):

Asked by many, The childs in list must **not** have width "match_parent" if you are looking for listview click only.

Even if you set the "Focusable" to false it wont work.
Set the child's Width to wrap_content

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemchild"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution and the easiest way I can provide is this. You just need to do these two steps.

1.add this in your XML file.

```js
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info_text"
        />
```

2. Add this in your MainActivity file.

```js
        ListView listView;
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        String[] fruits = new String[5];
        fruits[0]="hello";
        fruits[1]="hello";
        fruits[2]="hello";
        fruits[3]="hello";
        fruits[4]="hello";

        List newList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(fruits));
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(DisplayPannel.this, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
        });
```