# listView item listeners

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, reference

When using a `listView` I noticed that, on setting up a `checkBox` in a listView, the `listView.OnItemClicked` listener does not work ! For now, I am trying to implement **two different** `on click listeners` for the `listView`. The first one is for the **listView body** and the second one for the **listView's body's checkBox**. The listView's body is to (for now) generate a toast and the checkBox is to generate a another toast(for now).

The problem I am facing is when referring to `checkBox.onClick`
the logic is only implemented to the last(or any random,but only one) checkbox in the layout.

The listView layout looks like this:

[image]

**MainActivity.java**:

```
    private void registerClickCallBack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewComplex);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Random clickedRandom = randomList.get(position);
                String message = "You have clicked position "+position+" which is titled "+clickedRandom.getTitle();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final CheckBox check= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxComplex);
                check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(check.isChecked()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Comment: I am still unsure of what you need and what you are trying to do. I assume you need to display a toast when you check the check box coz that's what you say in the below comments. If so try the below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this

```
  android:focusable="false"
```

to checkbox in xml.

Assuming you want to dispaly a toast on click of a check box. Try the below

You should use a view holder for smooth scrolling and performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Initialize your listiew in `onCreate`. From your previous code before the edit i could see you intializing listview twice. No need for that.

Change you activity to

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private List<Random> randomList = new ArrayList<Random>();
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<Random> adapter;
    private  SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewComplex);
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        populateRandomList();
        populateListView();
        registerClickCallBack();
    }

    private void populateRandomList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        randomList.add(new Random("Title One", "Simple", "Status: OK", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        randomList.add(new Random("Title Two", "Complex", "Status: WORKING", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        randomList.add(new Random("Title Three", "Moderate", "Status: NOT OK", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        randomList.add(new Random("Title Four", "Simple", "Status: BAD", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        randomList.add(new Random("Title Five", "Moderate", "Status: NOT OK", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        randomList.add(new Random("Title Six", "Simple", "Status: WORKING",R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        randomList.add(new Random("Title Seven", "Complex", "Status: EXCELLENT", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        randomList.add(new Random("Title Eight", "Complex", "Status: NBA", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Random> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

        public MyListAdapter(){
            super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.layout_complex,randomList);
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(randomList.size());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return randomList.size();
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder vh;
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_complex,parent,false);
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                vh.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
                vh.titleText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
                vh.typeText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemType);
                vh.statusText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemStatus);
                vh.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxComplex);
                convertView.setTag(vh); 
        } else { 
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        } 

            Random currentItem = randomList.get(position);
            vh.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getIconID());
            vh.titleText.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
            vh.typeText.setText(currentItem.getType());
            vh.statusText.setText(currentItem.getStatus());
            vh.cb.setTag(position);
            vh.cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            vh.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            return convertView;

        }
         public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

            }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
             mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
             if(isChecked)
                {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checked at "+(Integer) buttonView.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }
        class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView titleText,typeText,statusText;
            ImageView imageView;
            CheckBox cb;
        }
    }

    private void registerClickCallBack() {
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position,
                    long id) {
                Random clickedRandom = randomList.get(position);
                String message = "You have clicked position "+position+" which is titled "+clickedRandom.getTitle();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: @Arash thank you. i was unsure of what op wanted or else i could have posted the solution a bit earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415566/2812681