# OnClickListener event not working in linear layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have `LinearLayouts` acting as a `listView` I want to add `onClickListener` on the rows of the `list`.
The code is inside a `fragment`.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    for (int i = 0; i < promos.size(); i++) {
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, lv, false);
        holder = new NewsHolder();
        news = (News) promos.get(i);
        holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.title.setText(news.title);
        holder.excerpt.setText(news.excerpt);
        lv.addView(rowView);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"clicked item"+news.id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
    mainL.addView(linear);
    return mainL;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call `show()` on the `Toast`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please paste the error code

Comment: No error it just doesn't show the toast message.

Comment: Do you have something else inside the row `View` besides the `TextView`? Post the `list_item` layout.

Comment: Yes it contains image view and another text view.I didn't show all of it for simplicity. 
Thanks I found it I forgot to add 
android:clickable="true" for the main layout.

Comment: Can you edit the latest code after the comment mention by @Mike M.

Comment: lv.addView(rowView); add this line after setting the click listner

Comment: Solved I forgot to add  android:clickable="true" to the list_item.xml.

Comment: What is lv here

Comment: LinearLayout acting as a listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the rowView inside your Linearlayout after defining onclicklistner like this,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

for (int i = 0; i < promos.size(); i++) {
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, lv, false);
    holder = new NewsHolder();
    news = (News) promos.get(i);
    holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.title.setText(news.title);
    holder.excerpt.setText(news.excerpt);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"clicked item"+news.id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    lv.addView(rowView);

}
mainL.addView(linear);
return mainL;
}
```

Comment: Solved I forgot to add android:clickable="true" to the list_item.xml

Answer (score 0):

Added android:clickable="true" to the list_item.xml.

Answer (score -4):

Looks like you searching for solution like in this topic. Read here [ListView with OnItemClickListener android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645880/listview-with-onitemclicklistener-android)

Comment: I don't use ListView.