# Setting Listener on individual item of custom adapter list view

Tags: android

I am trying to populate a custom listview adapter from a database and set onItemClickListener on each item. But where should i put the listener? Its not working when i put it in the main Activity class.

Main Activity class:

```
clist=db.getAllContacts ();
myAdapter=new MyAdapter (MainActivity.this, (ArrayList<Contact>) clist);
lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

            //Some code to work on the Items
        }
    });
```

Adapter class MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Contact user = getItem (position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from (getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.listviewadapter, parent, false);
    }
    TextView name = convertView.findViewById (R.id.name);
    TextView num = convertView.findViewById (R.id.num);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object

    name.setText (user.name);
    num.setText (user.phone_number);


    return convertView;
}
```

}

List Item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Number"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: You may consider use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`

Comment: I am new to android so i am yet to learn about recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your item listener is not working then you can apply this on ListView in xml layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

You can put many clicks listeners if you need in adapter class like

```
   public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
        Context context;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> users) {
            super(context, 0, users);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Contact user = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listviewadapter, parent, false);
            }
            TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView num = convertView.findViewById(R.id.num);
            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object

            name.setText(user.name);
            num.setText(user.phone_number);
            // can set click on name or num
            name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, position + "position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            // can set click on full list item
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, position + "position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also want to track which item is clicked but by your method i can only know whether the listview is clicked or not.

Comment: It worked. thanks!. Can you explain me why it doesn't work when i use it in the main activity inside the onitemclick listener?

Comment: Can you place your list item xml in your question, so that i can tell this. This issue persist when you have some clickable item in your list item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and your listener will work :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

on the first parent layout inside the list.
Answer credits : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/13415566

Hope this helps !

Comment: This does not work when i am using the list through an adapter.