# How to set list item click listener correctly in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I'm learning android development. I'm trying to set OnItemClickListener but it doesn't work. I have this MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    products.add(new Product("product one",100, R.drawable.one, 1));
    products.add(new Product("product two",200, R.drawable.two, 2));
    products.add(new Product("product three",170, R.drawable.three, 3));
    products.add(new Product("product four",220, R.drawable.four, 4));
    products.add(new Product("product five",300,R.drawable.five, 5));
    products.add(new Product("product six",130, R.drawable.six, 6));
    products.add(new Product("product seven",100, R.drawable.seven, 7));
    products.add(new Product("product eight",240, R.drawable.eight, 8));
    products.add(new Product("product nine",190, R.drawable.nine, 9));
    products.add(new Product("product ten",150, R.drawable.ten, 10));

    ProductAdapter itemsAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, products);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext() , "Welcome" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

  }
}
```

And this Product class

```
public class Product {
  private String mProductName;
  private int mProductPrice;
  private int mProductImage;
  private int mProductId;

  public Product(String productName, int productPrice, int productImage, int productId){
    mProductName = productName;
    mProductPrice = productPrice;
    mProductImage = productImage;
    mProductId = productId;
  }

  public String getProductName(){

    String upperString = mProductName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + mProductName.substring(1);

    return upperString;
  }

  public int getProductPrice(){ return mProductPrice; }

  public int getProductImage() { return mProductImage;  }

  public int getProductId() { return mProductId; }
}
```

list_item: contains full layout. Nested LinearLayouts to design the list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="90dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        style="@style/lisTxt"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
        style="@style/lisTxt"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_to_cart"
        android:text="Add To Cart"
        style="@style/listBtn"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_now"
        android:text="Buy Now"
        style="@style/listBtn"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I click on any list item it doesn't trigger anything. Where's the issue and how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your list item layout XML? And snippet code of `getView` in your adapter?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645880/listview-with-onitemclicklistener-android) will help you

Comment: @Aaron list_item has been added trying to add more code still can't

Answer (score 0):

Added this line to the list item layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

list_item parent LinearLayout looks like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```