# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() is not working in my customAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

please refer this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zoj9lw10oc07xa/to_dropbox.png

**`what i am doing :`**
i am creating a list_view , in which i am adding custom adapter .

**`what i am using :`**
i am using , listView , customAdapter , menuitem .
`listView` : single listview in whole application 
`customadapters` : 3 custom adapters 
`menuitem` : 1

**`How i am implementing :`**
i have data base from which things are fetched properly , and from that database i have entered these values in my listview by filtering that data in 3 types :
1st adapter_type is entered by default ( in onCreate ) .

```
adapter = new Adapter_forCompletedReminder( array_today_title , this) ;
ls.setAdapter(adapter) ;
```

2nd adapter_type is entered in my listview by pressing menuitem .

```
adapter = new Adapter_forCompletedReminder( array_past_2_day_title , this) ;
ls.setAdapter(adapter) ;
```

3rd adapter_type is entered in my listview by pressing menuitem .

```
adapter = new Adapter_forCompletedReminder( array_other_day_title , this) ;
ls.setAdapter(adapter) ;
```

**`what is my problem :`**
this code is added inside onCreate() method .

```
ls.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView , View view , int position ,long arg3) 
    {
        Log.i("Item clicked","tushar:itemclicked") ;
    }
});
```

when i have tried to implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() , it is not working ... 
code is not crashing ( no red lines in log cat ).
code is not executing in the click of llist_view_element

thanks , for reading my problem .

Comment: maybe your views has intercept touching events. try to add onClick action to your convertView in adapters getView() method.

Comment: can you provide Adapter_forCompletedReminder code?

Comment: my adapter_file_is : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ij13ibz3aeqhatz/Adapter_forCompletedReminder.java

Comment: Your code is correct.
My advice is that first use only one adapter then check onItemclick listener is working or not.

Comment: try to add onClickListener to your view in getView() method (before return v;)

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji , your 1st comment reply : https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xei0tl7z4f21ot/background.png , thats why i have to need the whole listview .

Comment: can you post Activity class, where you managing ListViews adapter?

Comment: MainActivity class : https://www.dropbox.com/s/4id1mmbs4ewq39z/Completed.java

Comment: no problems detected in your MainActivity. Possible you have redundant properties in your xml files (R.layout.completed_xml, R.layout.customview_completedxml_listview).

Comment: Try to declare it like that : ls.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) { ... }

Comment: please put customview_completedxml_listview.xml file

Comment: @pawanyadav , customview_completedxml_listview.xml :: https://www.dropbox.com/s/szuex71tssj1t4k/customview_completedxml_listview.xml

Comment: Suggest you check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14372750/565433 Worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use checkbox in customview_completedxml_listview.xml that is why onItemClick listener is not working. If you set clickable = "false" in checkbox then onItemclick listener will work.

If you want want that checkbox will stil work then you have to set onclicklistener event in you custom adapter class.

// I edit getView

```
 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
   { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ob) ; 
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customview_completedxml_listview, null ) ; 


     TextView txt = ( TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_fordisplayingdata) ; 
      txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Toast.makeText(ob, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
      txt.setText(recieved_Array[position]) ; 

      return v ; 
   }
```

///////////////////////
// Second solution set android:focusable="false" in checkbox

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
       > 

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txt_fordisplayingdata"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:text="display data"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    /> 

  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txt_fordisplayingLargerdata"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:text="display data larger bahut larger "
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    /> 

  <View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_fordisplayingdata"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/view_forcompletedtask"
    /> 


  <CheckBox 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_forcompletedtask"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_tocomplete"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Tushar Pandey I hope it will work i provide two solution both will work select according to your implementation

Answer (score 9):

Here are few things you can try :-

1. If there is any button(or checkbox) or any element in your listview item which handles click event then do this for each element:-

   ```
   android:focusable = "false"  
   android:focusableInTouchMode = "false"
   ```
2. Try setting this

   ```
   list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
   ```
3. Override the onItemClick() method

   ```
   ls.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()  
   {  
   @Override  
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView , View view , int position ,long arg3)   
   {  
       Log.i("Item clicked","tushar:itemclicked") ;  
   }  
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, nr.1 worked for me. Answers on other posts suggested `android:clickable="false"` would do the trick alone, but not for me. The 'focusable's worked perfect. Maybe there's a difference between emulator and device here..

Answer (score 1):

I really can't say what exactly problem you have, but I wrote very simple example for you. Try it, and if it works - just port your current project into my sample project. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz4Xd7Ju_kbYbVlyd1dvYTJZYTg/edit?usp=sharingalways

**P.S.:** I recommend you to read about "best practices in `Android`", when you finish your idea ( about `ViewHolder` pattern).

Comment: I will , but it is a long .. project there are 6-7 sections inside it .

Comment: try to add onClickListener to your view in getView() method (before return v :) this Answer is in the way to Rock .

Comment: just open project and test if works. after that you can compare your project with this example and possible you will find bug "why onClick doesn't work". onClickListener for view in getView() not needed in your project, because you have simple list logic. seems like you have redundant attributes in your xml layouts.

Comment: you using checkBox in your layout, that was intercepting touch events on your list row. set next property for your checkBox: "clickable = false" in customview_completedxml_listview.xml