# How to get the list item name by click on it?

Tags: android

I wrote a program to retrieve all the saved contact in android device. Code works fine but now I want to get the contact name and number by clicking on the list item. For this, I have used a custom list view (which includes imageview, 2 text views and one checkbox).

I wrote "setOnItemClickListner" method to get the contact name, but when I click on any list item It doesn't show a toast message (showing contact name). How to fix this?

This is the MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    ListView list;
    public String contactName;
    public String contactNumber;
    public String name;
    public String number;

    // array list
    ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listContact);
        fetchContact(); // call fetch contact method


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void fetchContact(){
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = null;

        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,sortOrder);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            // object for contact class
            Contact contact = new Contact(contactName,contactNumber);
            // add contact object to array list
            contactList.add(contact);
        }

        sortList(); // call sort list method

        // setting custome adapter
        contactAdapter adapter = new contactAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.activity_list_item,contactList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // list item click listner
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               /* contactName = contactList.get(i).getName();
                contactNumber = contactList.get(i).getNumber();*/

                name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                number = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact Name : " + name + "\n"+ "Contact Number : " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sortList(){
        // sort array list
        Collections.sort(contactList, new Comparator<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Contact contact, Contact t1) {
                return contact.getName().compareTo(t1.getName());
            }
        });


    }
}

This the contact class 
public class Contact {
    // properties
    public String name;
    public String number;

    // constructor
    public Contact(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Contact() {
    }

    // getter and setter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

This is the custome layout I build
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ContactInfoActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <!--Banner-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#199FD5"/>

    <!--Circle image-->
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPerson"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBanner"
        android:src="@drawable/person"/>

    <!--Contact name & number-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgPerson"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Number"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <!--Image-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNumber"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_call"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_message"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

This is the custom adapter (contact adapter)
package com.example.contact4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class contactAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private static final String TAG = "contactAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    // constructor
    public contactAdapter (Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Contact> object)
    {
        super(context,resource,object);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // get the contact information
        String name = getItem(position).getName();
        String number = getItem(position).getNumber();

        // create the contact object with the information
        Contact contact = new Contact(name,number);

        LayoutInflater inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource,parent,false);

        TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView tvNumber= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);

        tvName.setText(name);
        tvNumber.setText(number);

        return convertView;
    }`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16915420/11555903) , it might help you since you are using checkboxes.

Comment: Could you provide the contactAdapter and the list item layout xml file as well?

Comment: try that in your onclickitemlistener `adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).ToString`

Comment: @sausagerus thanks man., it worked.,And thank u all of u for helping me.