# Trying to catch a click on android ListView item: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" not working

Tags: android, listview

This has been addressed in many posts on StackOverflow.  The most recommended solution is to set:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

on the root layout of the list item layout.  I've done the following.

- Set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the root
  list item layout.
- Called `setDescendantFocusability(BLOCK)` on the listView, as well as
  each listViewItem.
- Set `focus=disabled` on the ImageButtons

However when one of the child ImageButtons is clicked, I can't get any listeners on the `ListView` or `ListView` Items to fire.

Below is the "template" I am using to render a list item.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reminderItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:padding="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topPartOfReminder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:text="10:00"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:id="@+id/textTime"/>
                <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:textSize="9sp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="AM"
                        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:id="@+id/textAmPm"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text=" - "
                        android:id="@+id/textDivider"/>
                <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="March 26"
                        android:id="@+id/textDate"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text="Blah blah blah blah"
                    android:id="@+id/textDescription"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textLayout"
                android:gravity="right">

            <ImageButton
                    style="@style/HorizontalButton"
                    android:id="@+id/shiftButton"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_forward"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                    style="@style/HorizontalButton"
                    android:id="@+id/repeatButton"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                    style="@style/HorizontalButton"
                    android:id="@+id/tickButton"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_done"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tickButtonsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="OK"/>
        <View style="@style/VerticalDivider"/>
        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="Cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/repeatButtonsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="day"/>
        <View style="@style/VerticalDivider"/>
        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="weekday"/>
        <View style="@style/VerticalDivider"/>
        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="week"/>
        <View style="@style/VerticalDivider"/>
        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="month"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/shiftButtonsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="1 week"/>
        <View style="@style/VerticalDivider"/>
        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="1 day"/>
        <View style="@style/VerticalDivider"/>
        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="1 hour"/>
        <View style="@style/VerticalDivider"/>
        <Button style="@style/HorizontalButton" android:text="10 mins"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Am also setting this descendantFocusability in the code, just to be sure:

```
public class ReminderItemAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    . . .

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_item, parent, false);
        parent.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        ((ViewGroup) v).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        return v;
    }
```

And on the styling of my ImageButton's I've set focusable=false, just for good measure:

```
<resources>
    <style name="HorizontalButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">false</item>
    </style>
    . . .
```

I am getting onClick's received when clicking on any part of the list item, including the child TextView elements.  However when clicking on any of the ImageButtons, the click's don't get picked up.  (BTW I have got OnClickListeners registered with the ImageButtons and they are getting called.)

Have set:

- setOnItemClickListener on ListView
- setOnItemSelectedListener on ListView
- setOnClickListener on each ListView Item.

But none of these get called if one of the ImageButtons is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

Try using this inside each button layouts

```
 android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and remove other thing which you are doing for this.
Also from listview.
Also remove this

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and this too

```
parent.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        ((ViewGroup) v).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: When you say "button layouts", do you mean the actual ImageButton elements, or on the layouts which are holding these buttons?  Cheers.

Comment: Did exactly as you described.  Behavior remains the same.  The listener for the actual ImageButton is called. But none of the listeners for the ListView or ListView items get called.

Comment: Remove these also    parent.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        ((ViewGroup) v).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

Comment: Can confirm that any call of setDescendantFocusability was removed, but behaviour is still the same.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

> Just put `android:focusable="false"`  in the row/item.xml of the listView .

It solve all your problem. if you put an `event listener on the listView` .. It will not let you click on whole ListView Row. I mean

`listView.setOnClickListener(this);` will not be called . because the focus moves to the `row/item of the listView` . By adding  `android:focusable="false"` to the Button or ImageView on which you put an Event . **It will lose their focus and the focus is gain by listView.** Now you can have `listView clickable as well as its descendents rows/item..`

In short just put  `android:focusable="false`  in `TextView/Button or ImageView` which have event Listeners in the Item/row.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding android:clickable="false" for the buttons? I just ran into a similar issue and that fixed it for me, whereas using android:focusable="false" did not.

Good luck!