# why my ListView never calls onItemClick?

Tags: android, listview

I have really searched a lot on google, stack overflow , and found this : [OnItemCLickListener not working in listview ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android). But seems sunshine's answer not works for my case. Other answers are all similar ones.

I have tried the following approaches:

add `android:focusable="false"` to my list item xml

add `TextView.setFocusable(false)` and `TextView.setClickable(false)` in ViewHolder

using the xml as described in the above link.

But none of them work.

Here's my xml and java code:

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ninegrid_number_list_choice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ninegrid_number_listchoice_text_size"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

`getView` int list adapter.java:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null ) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ninegrid_number_list_choice);
            holder.mTextView.setFocusable(false);
            holder.mTextView.setClickable(false);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mTextView.setText(mList.get(position));
        holder.mTextView.setTextColor(mTextColor);
        holder.mTextView.setFocusable(false);
        holder.mTextView.setClickable(false);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Edit:
in my activity:

```
 listchoice.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
 listChoice.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {

      Log.v(tag, "sdf");
 }
 });
```

Comment: You aren't showing us the code where you register the onItemClick listener. Are you registering the listener properly?

Comment: where are you setting the onItemClickListener(), show that code !!

Comment: I've never used `setClickable(false)` or `setFocusable(false)` on the subviews in the `getView` method. Maybe that's causing issues?

Comment: @Tenfour04, there's time i didn't add the two calls, but the result is same.

Comment: remove this listchoice.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS); and the clean and build your project and run may be it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnItemCLickListener not working in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

On method getView() of the adapter, you can set the onclick event of convertView before returning it.
That event handler can be treated as onItemClick :)

Comment: Yes, i know this. But while I'm also using `listSelector`. I have tested that if i set click listener for the textView, the list selector will not work. So what should i do then?

Answer (score 0):

The listview click listener not working when we use buttons,imagebutton etc. As you use only textview so there will not be problem like that...
As you used linearlayout no need to use `android:focusable="false"` in your linear layout.
We used this code only during usage of buttons. Also no need to use code  `holder.mTextView.setClickable(false);`
As text is not a button so it takes no any focus. When u clicked it will click on the list cell not on the textview...
So Simply inflate and then after setting custom adapter to the listview...
setonitemclicklistner to the list view....

**UPDATED ANSWER**

convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));

This will surely works...

Comment: i removed the call to `setClickable` and `android:focusable`, but still no help

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and tried all suggested solutions but none worked for me. After trying out different things, I found out there was another reason for my problem. I was wrapping my list_item inside a `ScrollView`, which was causing my `onItemClick` to not be called. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seems to override the row clicks is if you have textviews, make sure they don't have an android:inputtype associated with them
remove the inputtype and you can click the row
This is in addition of course to the above answers on