# Context menu not coming for listview

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a list view. I have added an `onclick` method in the adapter `getview` function for the row of listview and it works fine.

Now I have added a context menu:

```
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

and have implemented `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected`

But the longclick is not working . It is taken as single click and does the onclick functionality

I even added  `android:longClickable="true"` for the xml file inflated for the listview row.

It also didn't help.

Comment: can You show what You have done?

Comment: if the on click method is still then in the getview method of your adapter then the long click of item wont be working. As the child is hiding click event of parent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android/14372750#14372750 check this.

Comment: it is a different issue where onclick is not working because of some item being focussable