# OnItemClicked not getting called in ListView

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I've read as many examples as i could find and it seems like i am implementing this correctly but the click never registers. My OnItemClicked Listener is not getting called though it seems to be implemented correctly.

```
public class Playlist extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private int list_layout = R.layout.playlist;
    private Context context;
    private PlaylistAdapter adapter;
    private Cursor cursor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(list_layout);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();
        adapter = new PlaylistAdapter(context, cursor, FLAGS);
        ListView list_view = getListView();
        list_view.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(Playlist.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startSong(position);
    }
}
```

ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff525252"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:background="#ffafafaf"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/songname"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="1sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>

   <Button>
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/artistname"
        android:textColor="#ff585858"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songname"
        android:padding="1sp"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*EDIT*: Sorry. I did not mean for this to be such a bad question. I will do my best to salvage it.

Comment: did you know the import meaning android.R...?

Answer (score 1):

Add entire `XML` code to your question(if you used `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`)

and check `android:id="@+id/list"`

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            startSong(arg2);

        }
    });
```

or try with your getView parameter View/inflate list item onclick listener

```
     view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                 //do stuff
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    try {

                         //  YOUR STUFF


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in Xml File on Listview

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="#ff525252"
     android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Sorry my question was unclear. I will try to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are many duplicate questions of this type, but the one that turned out to be relevant to my problem was solved [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android).

"If any row item of list contains focusable or clickable view then OnItemClickListener won't work."

The row item must have a param like android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:background="#ffafafaf"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
```