# ItemClickListener is not working on Clicking Navigation Drawer List Item

Tags: android, android-layout

I can open drawer with entries in the array specified only problem is i click is not listened
The Layout file for my app is here.......[clarifying] Drawer List is at the end in drawerlayout after all other layouts. ie. scroll/linear.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    >
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg015"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvEvents"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:background="#555555"
             android:text="Today&apos;s Events"
             android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
             android:textSize="18sp" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/scheduleView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvEvents"
         android:layout_height="209dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvClasses"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scheduleView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:text="Today&apos;s Classes"
        android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/classesView"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvClasses"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="210dp" />



         <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/tvTasks"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/classesView"
             android:text="Today&apos;s Task"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
             android:background="#555555"
             android:textSize="18sp" />

          <ListView
              android:id="@+id/taskView"
              android:layout_below="@+id/tvTasks"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="210dp"
          />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:entries="@array/main_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Activity wher i am opening drawer and clicking the drawer element is here....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView drawer_list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer_list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drawer);
        drawer_list.setClickable(true);
        drawer_list.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

        drawer_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("clicked",""+position);

                }
                  });
        }

    }
```

Comment: MyDrawer.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.my_drawer_row));

Comment: @Hamidreza couldn't get you, can you explain it plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to set the `adapter` of your `listview`:

```
drawer_list.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

**UPDATE**

Try to add :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

To your `listview` item's `xml` most outer layout.

Example :

[OnItemCLickListener not working in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android)

Comment: Blaze m specifying list item through xml, android:enteries, in that case is ther any need for dapter? i think no.

Comment: @RazaQuaidian sorry never use that. Please post your list item xml

Comment: i have tried android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" but still not working.

Comment: @RazaQuaidian please post your item.xml otherwise i cant find your problem :)

Comment: android:entries="@array/main_menu"  here in listview i am refering to an array resource blaze.. that is shown but not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh atlast i did it, it may not be a case with someone else but i am still posting as a new android learner may can face this type of situation.
-The problem was with my onResume() function, i was using setContentView(layout) in onResume() and was doing it in onCreate() as well, it was causing not to fire onClickListener(),