# android listview under fragment onItemClick not working

Tags: android

Don't know why the onItemClick event not working...

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
    View rootView;
    ListView list;


    public FragmentList (){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                Log.i("test", String.valueOf(position));

                }
            });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Anyone has idea on this. thanks so much

Comment: you did not set your adapter for that listview therefore no cliking can be registered.

Comment: your Listview size = 0, width = 0, height = 0 because of no child. So where the place u can click in this? You need setadapter first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any row item of list contains focusable or clickable view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work.

The row item must have a param like `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android) for more information.

Comment: I have a listview inside a fragment. When clicking an item, it will jump to a detail fragment by replacing. However, when I click the back button from the detail fragment, it jumps back to the listview fragment that requiring to load all the data again. Is it possible to keep all the listview item and status when back. Thanks.

Comment: @user3691709，you can judge if your rootView empty or not when call onCreateView method,and then decide if request to load all the data or not