# ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter OnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I can populate my list with the database values. My problem is that ListView layout looks like this (for example) -> ( textview, delete button )

Activity 1 || Delete_Button

Activity 2 || Delete_Button

and what i want is that when i clicked Activity 1, it will go to Activity 1 intent. or when i clicked Activity 2, it will go to Activity 2 intent. same as the delete button, if I clicked the row 1 delete button, it will delete row 1 and etc.

How to do this ? I'm new at Android.

**This is my code:**

```
 ListView listView ;
    ArrayList<String> list;

    public int goal_id;
    int i = 0;

    //database variables
    MyDBAdapter dbhandler;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_act);
            TypefaceProvider.registerDefaultIconSets();

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (extras == null) {
                return;
            }

            goal_id = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("goalid"));

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Activities List");
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Added new activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Added new activity", null).show();

                    onCLick_addAct();
                }
            });

            dbhandler = new MyDBAdapter(this);
            populateListView();
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Long temp = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
                    MessageTo.message(SetActActivity.this, Long.toString(temp));
                }
            });

        }

        public void populateListView(){
            Cursor cursor = dbhandler.getAllActivitiesByGoalCursor(goal_id);
            String[] actlist = new String[] {dbhandler.dbhandler.COLUMN_ACTIVITY_NAME};
            int[] actNames = new int[] {R.id.list_item_string};

            SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(SetActActivity.this,R.layout.act_list,cursor,actlist,actNames,0){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                ViewHolder holder;
                if (v == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.act_list, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
                    holder.button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
                    v.setTag(holder);
                    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                            list.remove(pos);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                } 
//  holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).get("title")); //the get("title") is error. undefined

                holder.button.setTag(position);
                return v;

            }

            class ViewHolder {
                TextView textView;
                Button button;
            }
        };
        //handle listview and assign adapter
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
```

This one code -> it wont distinguish if i clicked the textview or the delete button. It will still implement the same function which is not what i want to happen. :(

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        Long temp = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
                        MessageTo.message(SetActActivity.this, Long.toString(temp));
                    }
                });
```

Comment: you need to create custom SimpleCursorAdapter class and override getView() method and follow @Ichigo Kurosakio post.

Comment: how to override?? :( @bharat

Comment: on "delete" button clicked: do you really want to delete the corresponding row in the database?

Comment: but when i clicked the delete button , it just do nothing.

Comment: same as the textView in the listView

Comment: just wanted to make sure because if not a SimpleCursorAdapter would be useless. I think your Activity has to implement SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder and then you need to override "setViewValue()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a focusable item (`Button`) in a list which is overriding the event of `OnItemClickListener`. The solution is to use two separate `onClickListeners` while creating the views in the adapter.

This issue is pretty common. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android) for reference.

Now, the code for custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{

    private Context mContext;
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cr;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cr = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        RelativeLayout parentView = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
        TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemLayoutText);
        // Set the text using cursor with column index.
        textview.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.itemLayoutBtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // Use interface to send a callback to the activity
                Toast.makeText(context, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        parentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // Use interface to send a callback to the activity
                Toast.makeText(context, "List item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Layout of list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/parentView">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/itemLayoutText"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemLayoutBtn"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: textview.setText(cursor.getString(1)); <- can u explain to me the cursor.getString(1)? it prints the same text on textview in all list items

Comment: i know now thanks. THANKS FOR THIS ANSWER :) :) IT WORKS.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED** : As you can't delete a row/item from cursor and also re-query Cursor every time user presses delete not a good idea.
 **Instead** you can read all values from cursor and put it in `List<Map<String,String> items` and pass this object to `SimpleAdapter`. try below code.

```
    items = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    Map<String, String> item;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));//column name
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));//column name
        item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("title", name);
        item.put("id", id);
        items.add(item);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.adapter_text_button, new String[]{"title"
    }, new int[]{R.id.title}) {
        @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (v == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.adapter_text_button, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.action);
                v.setTag(holder);
                holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                        Map<String, String> item = items.get(pos);
                        String id = item.get("id");
                        //using this id delete the record from the database
                        items.remove(item);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Log.i("TAG", "ID " + id);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            Map<String, String> data = items.get(position);
            holder.textView.setText(data.get("title"));
            holder.button.setTag(position);
            return v;

        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
            Button button;
        }
    };

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: is this on another java class? or inside onCreate Method?

Comment: inside onCreate only.

Comment: my bad. i will try this.

Comment: you  cant remove a item from Cursor in that case you need to requery the query. is that ok.

Comment: should i use the deleteRow query then?

Comment: by the way, the activity names wont print on TextView. It disappear when i implement your code. or doesnt have any text on it/

Comment: yes you have to and call setAdapter again.. Activity names come from Db Right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100636/discussion-between-bharat-and-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add in your custom adapter's getView() method a setOnClickListener() for the buttons you're using.

Any data associated with the button has to be added with myButton.setTag() in the getView() and can be accessed in the onClickListener via view.getTag()

Check the solution in this [link](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html)

Comment: But im using the SimpleCursorAdapter.. :(