# Android Edittext and OnItemClickListner in ListView not working at the same

Tags: android, listview

I have a **ListView** and it contains an **Edittext** in it. When I click **Edittext** in the items of **ListView**, android keyboard get open.

But when I clicked row of the **ListView**, its onItemClick won't work. Then I searched stackoverflow and found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview) where someone advised to add this line in my custom layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

By adding this line to my layout, onItemClick started working. But editText is not getting input. My problem is how to make my **ListView Item** get input as well as **ListView Row** get onItemClick.

This is my listView below

```
   <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/lst1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit" />
```

This is my item Layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/RelMAn"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <EditText
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:id="@+id/edt1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/color_edittext"
        android:padding="7dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share a picture of your layout ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 I have shown the xml code of my layout above.

Answer (score 0):

use OnlongeClickListener for do item action because you can't use one listener for two action

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to implement long click listener.