# Android: OnItemClickListener is not working

Tags: android

The scenario is, there are two different functions which fetches data based on conditions and populates them into listview using CursorAdapter. I am able to display the data according to the condition but OnItemClickListener isnt working.

This i have initialized in onCreate:

```
 listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(Home.this, null, 0);
 LV_HomeDisp.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
 LV_HomeDisp.setOnItemClickListener(Home.this);
```

These are two functions:

```
 public void displayAllHomeData(){
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = dbHelper.getAllHomeData(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(Home.this, res, 0);
        LV_HomeDisp.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        LV_HomeDisp.setOnItemClickListener(Home.this);
 }
}
public void displayFilterHomeData(){

    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = dbHelper.getFilterHomeData(sqLiteDatabase, m_Text);

    if (res.moveToFirst()) {

            listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(Home.this, res, 0);
            LV_HomeDisp.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
             LV_HomeDisp.setOnItemClickListener(Home.this);

 }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrekDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("pos", id);

    //startActivity(intent);
}
```

I know there are many questions based on ClickListener. But I couldnt find any answer that could solve my problem. So please check before marking it duplicate. Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can check my answer in here. i think you have similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/26360393/1559852

Comment: Hi, I don't have anything clickable in my row items..so I dont thing that would solve the issue.

Comment: `startActivity` is commented. So it won't work.

Comment: would you please check your if statements? maybe res.moveToFirst() never returns true?

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal...Thanks man. I seriously cant believe I missed that. It was in front of my eyes the whole time. Thank you everyone for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment the `startActivity(intent);` statement. The `onItemClick` does nothing else that is visible.