# Why does adding a Button to (Android) ListView item shut down tap listener events for the item itself?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-button, onitemclicklistener

I have some pretty simple xml defining a ListView item.  Each item contains 2 TextView widgets and a Button.  I only added the Button yesterday, and suddenly taps on the ListView item itself no longer produce onItemClick() events.

I have reproduced this carefully and *simply removing the Button entry in the XML* for the ListItem allows the onItemClick() events to be fired.  Answers to other SO questions showed it is possible for controls placed on a ListView item could capture or otherwise prevent tap events from firing the listener (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview) for example).  So, hoping to find a workaround I added the following 3 lines to my TextView controls to no effect:

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
```

My xml displays everything properly and is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linLyt"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVal1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="0."
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVal2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight=".55"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClickMe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/CornflowerBlue"
        android:text="Click"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Again, just simply remove or comment out the Button xml and suddenly the listener begins firing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in your root layout of `listview` to make the listview Item click listener to work. `blocksDescendants` means that the `ViewGroup` will block its descendants from receiving focus.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:id="@+id/linLyt"
    >
```

in code:

```
yourListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
      // Your code for item click
   }
});
```

Now for Button click listener in listview row: You can set the `onClick()` event in your custom adapter's `getView()` method.

Comment: Sure enough that fixed it.  But why?  Why does adding a Button suddenly require setting the descendantFocusability attribute?  It was not needed before the Button was added.

Comment: `Button` is a focusable elements ...so it will automatically gets focus causing the list item click not to work..you can add `android:focusable="false"` in button xml. It should still be clickable, but will not get focus