# OnItemClickListener on Custom ListView Adapter is returning wrong data

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have a Custom Listview with a search bar which work perfectly. I now created an OnItemClickListener such that when i click my returned search item in the Listview it opens a new Activity with the selected items displayed in the new Activity. However the value returned when I click the Listview is wrong and I have been at this for over 3 days now and cannot seem to find the issue even when checking examples. Below is my code. I would appreciate any help in the right direction

this is my setOnItemClickListener in my MainActivity

```
 mListViewTakeAwayPacks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String takeAwayPack = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                    Toast.makeText(ListTakeAwayPackActivity.this, "Selected: " + takeAwayPack, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Cursor takeAwayPackData = controller.getTakeAwayPAckID(takeAwayPack);  //get the ID associatd with the name




                    while (takeAwayPackData.moveToNext()){

                     }
                        Intent editTakeAwayPackIntent = new Intent(ListTakeAwayPackActivity.this, EditTakeAwayPackActivity.class);
                        editTakeAwayPackIntent.putExtra("PackType", takeAwayPack);
                        startActivity(editTakeAwayPackIntent);

                }
            });
```

this is my Custom Adapter

```
public class TwoColumn_ListAdaper extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
   private ArrayList<User3> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
    private ArrayList<User3> mDisplayedValues;    // Values to be displayed
    LayoutInflater inflater;
   public TwoColumn_ListAdaper(Context context, int list_take_away_pack_adapter_view, ArrayList<User3> mProductArrayList){
       this.mOriginalValues = mProductArrayList;
        this.mDisplayedValues = mProductArrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDisplayedValues.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDisplayedValues.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {   // holds the views from the list_take_away_pack_ada[ter_view.xml, from the Textview and the parent Linear layout
        LinearLayout llContainer;
        TextView takeawaypacktype,takeawaypackprice;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parents){
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_take_away_pack_adapter_view, null);
            holder.llContainer = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
            holder.takeawaypacktype = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.takeawaypacktype);
            holder.takeawaypackprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.takeawaypackprice);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }      holder.takeawaypacktype.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getmTakeAwayPackType());      holder.takeawaypackprice.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getmTakeAwayPackCost()+"");
        holder.llContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        convertView.setClickable(false);    //add a single line of code like this: convertView.setClickable(false) because the OnItemCLickListener not working in listview.    found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview
        return convertView;
    }
```

This is the log file

```
2019-04-08 13:02:43.068 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@47d85e8 time:409548988
2019-04-08 13:02:45.921 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.071 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
2019-04-08 13:02:46.081 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.081 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement time:409552007
2019-04-08 13:02:46.101 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{98564ec V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
2019-04-08 13:02:46.171 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-04-08 13:02:46.201 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.201 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.211 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.211 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.221 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.221 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-04-08 13:02:46.231 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
2019-04-08 13:02:46.231 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b02ba23 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
2019-04-08 13:02:46.301 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 36 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-04-08 13:02:46.361 27225-27286/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa122f180 (ListView) with handle 0x9e18b930
2019-04-08 13:02:46.371 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2b43752 time:409552294
2019-04-08 13:02:46.581 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{5a8d6c0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@47d85e8 {com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement.Take_Away_Pack_Management.ListTakeAwayPackActivity}} show : false
2019-04-08 13:02:48.093 27225-27225/com.example.noruw.foodoclockbusinessprocessmanagement D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Comment: Can you tell what you got in **takeAwayPack** and what you were expecting

Comment: I have Take_Away_Pack_Details table with  2columns Pack_Type and Pack_Cost. Thy are listed in my 2column listview, my search filter searches successfully on Pack_type and opens a new Activity  and populates 2 EditText fields with Pack_type and Pack_Cost. Initially it was picking and populating PackType with the _ID. So if I selected the first Pack_Type it would populate with 1, if the 2nd item with _ID 2 etc, then I returned mDisplayedValues.get(position); in my getItem(int position) and it started returning the name of the java path of my custom class used to store my data

Comment: You said when you click on list item, you got wrong data. But didn't specified clearly what type of wrong data. Invalid (garbage data) or data of wrong index or any exception. I think you should show us the log of your output window

Comment: When I click on List item I get wrong data, I find I get the item _ID, for example when i click the first item in the list I get 1 passed, when i click the 2nd item I get 2 passed .. so it seems to be picking the _ID from the table instead of picking the PackType which is the 2nd column of three columns in the table after the _ID column. the log is above