# Android ListView onItemClickListener being blocked by ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, listview, clicklistener, focusable

I had my onItemClickListener working for my ListView inside of my DrawerLayout working fine. But I added a ProgressBar that is displayed before anything else then it is set to View.GONE.
However, I can't select and items from my list view any more.

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/device_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "Executing onCreate().");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.device_progress);
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    manager = MainScreenActivity.getDeviceManager();
    manager = MainScreenActivity.getDeviceManager();
    drawerInfo = manager.getDrawerInfo();
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.label, drawerInfo);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerLayout
            .setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDrawerClosed() executed!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(view);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDrawerOpened() executed!");
                    refreshDrawer();
                }
            });
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int pos, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CLICKED " + pos);
            selectDevice(pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am sure that adding the xml didn't break anything.. Haven't you modified something in your Java code?

Comment: @Waza_Be I added my Java code, when I comment out / delete the XML and Java code it works fine. So it's definitely because of the ProgressBar

Comment: Do you disable/hide listview before progressbar was shown? And do you enable/show listview after after progress bar was hidden? Add some code to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, instead of adding a new element inside of the Root DrawerLayout, put it inside of the FrameLayout where your main content should go. This was a dumb mistake by me, but if anyone else is having the same problem. Here it is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/device_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple View inside your DrawerLayout.
The [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) suggest you only have two!

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a
>   DrawerLayout object as the root view of your layout. Inside the
>   DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the
>   screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another
>   view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

I would suggest to group the ListvView and the ProgressBar in one container

Comment: How do I go about adding them in one container?

Comment: Have you heard about LinearLayout? Put both of them in one vertical LinearLayout

Comment: I tried this and it breaks it, I cannot pull out my drawer any more.
Changed code: http://pastebin.com/GCdYL4SB

Comment: Instead of asking what I obviously did, as you can see the code. Why don't you tell me what to do? Which, I did. You said put the progress bar and ListView in a linear layout. If I did in incorrectly, tell me how please. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am not you servant in front of a computer with developement IDE. I cannot give you code like this.. What I said WILL work. If you don't want to thank, try a little bit or to make effort, I wasted my time helping, and I feel annoyed

Comment: I am not saying you're my servant, but I apparently did something wrong, and instead of saying something useful you merely made a remark of apparently how obvious of a mistake I did ( Or atleast that was the tone I got) Sorry if that wasn't the tone. Did you look at the pastebin I posted. You can see I made a LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

Comment: As I cannot test YOUR code, I just tell you how to make it work: use 2 childrean in DrawerLayout. One with your main layout and one with your Drawer. Apparently, it doesn't work with the second layout you tried, but well with a simple ListView.. Why? I have no idea as I cannot test. Try with something simple, like a LinearLayout with a red background. If worked, add the list inside, if worked again, add progressbar. WHen it doesn't work, tell us at which step it stopped working

Comment: Alright, so I changed the gravity of the LinearLayout to left and it works and all, however, it makes it look very strange when I pull it out, I might be able to fix that my self. But now I get a ClassCastException when I do  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
Says it cannot cast LinearLayout, however, I am not giving it a linear layout.

Comment: You gave you listview a @id/drawer in your example, I am pretty sure you duplicated it to your LinearLayout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35462/discussion-between-waza-be-and-steve-jobs)

Comment: I am in the chat room.