# AutoCompleteTextView items are not clickable when using custom item layout

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm developing an application that uses AutoCompleteTextView and a custom item layout and I can't make item click action work.

Here is the custom item layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="viewModel" type="blog.liderc.familybudget.vms.DepartmentVM"/>
       <variable name="parentViewModel" type="blog.liderc.familybudget.AddSubjectViewModel"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
       <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="start"
               android:text="@{viewModel.title}"
               android:textSize="20sp"/>
       <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="end"
               android:text="x"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               android:onClick="@{() -> parentViewModel.deleteDepartmentAsync(viewModel)}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is how I configure that:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
   return activity?.let {
       val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
       val view = LayoutInflater
           .from(it)
           .inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_subject, null)

       viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(AddSubjectViewModel::class.java)
       viewModel.subject = SubjectVM()
       viewModel.departmentsAutoComplete = departments
       val app = it.application as FamilyBudgetApp
       viewModel.depsRepo = app.depsRepository.value

       val adapter = ObserverListAdapter(
           departments,
           R.layout.department_autocomplete,
           viewModel) { view.department.refreshAutoCompleteResults() }
       view.department.setAdapter(adapter)

       val binding: ViewDataBinding? = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)
       binding?.run {
           setVariable(BR.viewModel, viewModel)
           executePendingBindings()
       }
       builder.setView(view)
           .setPositiveButton("Remember", positive)
           .setNegativeButton("Nevermind") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
       builder.create()
   } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}
```

R.layout.department_autocomplete - is the custom item layout.

When I type into the corresponding AutoCompleteTextView field suggestions are being filtered and presented correctly but nothing happens when I hit any of them.

Here is how it looks:
[Autocomplete menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3zq1.png)

Comment: What did you expect would happen? You need to manually add the logic for what happens when you click on them

Comment: I expect the field to be filled when I click on an suggestions item. And this happens when I use android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line but for some reason this stops working when I use my custom layout. Also when I subscribe to AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener it isn't being fired when I hit an item.

Comment: Vucko, could you kindly provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same issue as you. You will have to make your own *onItemClick* event. Following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/autocomplete-textview-in-android-a1bf5fc112f6), you would need to set your own *onItemClickListener*.

It should look like this:

```
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // click event (such as filling the autocomplete section)
            }
        });
```

edit: I did not see your comment. Another thing I had to do was to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the `<LinearLayout>` from the `xml` file. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526198/onitemclicklistener-not-firing-on-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: This only line solved the issue: ```android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"```. Many thanks!